# cmake command to verify libraries?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

Is there a cmake command that is equivalent to "otool -L" ?

I would like to have this information for a third party library before I add it as a target to my project.

Comment: well you could call otool directly from cmake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CMake standard module [GetPrerequisites](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/GetPrerequisites.html). Example:

```
include(GetPrerequisites)
set (_recurse TRUE)
set (_exclude_system FALSE)
set (_verbose TRUE)
list_prerequisites("/usr/lib/libc.dylib" ${_recurse} ${_exclude_system} ${_verbose})
```